# R for loop dataframe variable names

Tags: r, loops, naming

I am new to R and loops. I have a data frame (`xyz`). I am running a loop and want to save a new new data frames under different names.

```
states <- c("AL",   "AK")
keywords <- c("snow", "rain")
filepath <- file.path("C:/data/")

for(state_var in states) 
for(key_var in keywords) 
{
save(xyz, file = (file.path(filepath, paste0(state_var, sep = "_", key_var,".RData"))))
}
```

Everything is working perfectly and new data frame is saved under different names. But when I load saved data frames all data frames have exactly same name `xyz`.

How it is possible to save under different df name. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you load the saved dataframes back?

Comment: I was just using `load(file.path(filepath, "AL_snow.RData"))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
states <- c("AL",   "AK")
keywords <- c("snow", "rain")

for(state_var in states) 
  for(key_var in keywords) 
  {
    objname <- paste(state_var, key_var, sep="_")
    assign(objname, xyz)
    save(list = objname, file = (file.path(filepath, paste0(state_var, sep = "_", key_var,".RData"))))
    rm(objname) # make sure you get rid of this again
  }
```

Save stores the saved object *as is*. That includes the name. With `assign` you create a new variable with the name you want.

Comment: Hi @Jan I am getting following error: object ‘assign("objname", xyz)’ not found

Comment: You're right. Wow! Fascinating!! The object existed but somehow save wasn't able to work with it. I fixed it. Tested it to the end this time.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for everyone. I was able to solve this question. It turns that `assign` does not work inside the function. And we have to use the `list`.
Here is the solution:

```
states <- c("AL",   "AK")
keywords <- c("snow", "rain")
filepath <- file.path("C:/data/")

for(state_var in states) 
for(key_var in keywords) 
{
assign(paste(state_var, key_var, sep="_"), xyz)
save(list = paste(state_var, key_var, sep="_"), file = (file.path(filepath, paste0(state_var, sep = "_", key_var,".RData"))))
}
```